# How to use macro or variable to shorten the make file?

Tags: makefile

I am using a make file for cross compilation of an Opencv project, in that I have to use a common path name many times, for eg, /home/to/the/loc/ , /home/to/the/loc/one , /home/to/the/loc/two ,..
Is there any way to shorten the common path by ? like by defining a variable or macro like 
INC_PATH=/home/to/the/loc .And, reuse by $(INC_PATH) ?
Is it possible? If not please suggest some other method

Comment: Wouldn't just trying it have been much, much faster than asking on SO and waiting for an answer?

Comment: I tried in many ways, but i couldn't find a solution,I don't even know whether is it possible ?

Comment: Well, what you provided in your question WILL work.  You can assign a variable as you show, and refer to it as you show.  So maybe if you gave us an actual example of what you tried, showed the command you ran, and showed the results you got and explained how they were different than what you wanted, we can explain what you're doing wrong.